# What does the square bracket mean when used with binary relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, relations

I'm confused what the square bracket means when dealing with binary relations.

[image]

What does R[A$\cup$B] mean? What does the square brackets around the A$\cup$B mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that $R$ is not a function, but a binary relation, and we perhaps define
$$
R[A] = \{b \;:\; \exists a \in A, aRb\}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$R$ is a set mapping (may not be functional), and the brackets are just brackets.   $R[A\cup B]$ is the set mapped to by the relation $R$ from the union of sets $A$ and $B$.   That is, the image of $A\cup B$.

Comment: Technically, $R$ is not a function, isn't it?

Comment: that is a fair point.